# Record & Share video in Unity Run time

Tags: unity-game-engine, record

In my project, I want to record the gameplay (Screen) and share the gameplay video on social media. I tried some record & replay samples. but which stores the object transforms and moves the recorded transform on replay time. any ideas or references will be helpful!!!!
Example: CoC attack and defend replay system

Comment: Are you trying to stream the video to media platforms live or just record the gameplay?

Answer (score 0):

You can use packages from the unity asset store to achieve this (you will have to pay for Pro version to get all required platforms etc)

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/easy-screen-recording-free-version-cross-platform-replay-kit-191899

There are a couple other different ones, but this records what is currently showing on screen.